# machine learning model true negative rate is too low while true positive rate is too high

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, text-mining, unbalanced-classes, h2o

I am using the tm package and h2o package to do text mining using neural network. Here I have a data frame of 100 most frequent words in the text. These variables only have values of non-negative integers. I am predicting a binary variable called "response". After multiple attempts, my true negative rates remain very low. 
Here is the confusion matrix:

```
Confusion Matrix for F1-optimal threshold:

__________0      1    Error           Rate
0      10049  83784 0.892905   =83784/93833
1       3272 134237 0.023795   =3272/137509


Totals 13321 218021 0.376309  =87056/231342
```

As you can see, the true negative rate is too low and true positive rate is too high (137509 actual 1s and 93833 actual 0s). i even attempted decision tree method but result is similar. I want to have a better balance between these two values. I am not sure if this is caused by the data itself or my original frequency data frame. How should I tune the parameters/what better ML model should I use?

Also, I performed table function on my original data. The percentage of 1 is indeed $59\%$, not $94\%$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there is a clear class imbalance with 218,021 1's and just 13,321 0's. This will result in a large imbalance in your model. The trivial accuracy of your data set is

$$\frac{218,021}{231,342}\times 100 = 94\%$$

This is if you label every observation as a 1.

Your accuracy is,

$$\frac{144,286}{231,342} = 62\%$$

Clearly, your model is performing worst than the trivial case which should be your baseline.

The obvious but commonly infeasible solution is to get more data for the other class.

The other solution is to change the training data set, this is done by resampling methods. Since you have a good amount of observations, you can undersample observations from the 1's class to obtain a training data set of fairly even classes. A lot of these methods are well explained on [this website](http://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/).

Always remember to perform EDA before constructing a model. A lot of these problems can be recognized early into the model construction process.

Comment: In my original dataset, I have 59% 1s and the rest are 0. I don't think there is an imbalance in my dataset. The problem here is my model predicts too many 1s than zeros while 59% of the original data is 1.

Comment: The confusion matrix has actual on its columns and predicted on its rows. The number of 1's is true positive+false negative, which is 218,021. The number of zeros is true negative+false positive, which is 13,321. That makes the percentage of ones (218,021/(218,021+13,321))=94%

Comment: No. I have my original data and I perform table function on it. The percentage of 1 is 59%. Ignore what I originally have in confusion matrix. Thank you.

Comment: Thats not the only solutions. The proper thing to do is to build a model that predicts probabilities.  I do not think the advice in that article is good.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [this](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/deep-learning.html)?

From the documentation:

> weights_column: Specify a column to use for the observation weights, which are used for bias correction.
>
> balance_classes: (Applicable for classification only) Specify whether to oversample the minority classes to balance the class distribution.